# Notifications still show up as unread on desktop, even if they were viewed and responded to from the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, notifications

I am trying out the Stack Exchange Android app, and tried responding to new notifications from my phone itself. While that part went smoothly, the desktop web version shows all those notifications as unread.

I have to view them in the desktop browser to get them to the *read* status on the desktop.

Comment: Related, probably a dupe: [Mobile notifications unread status independent from full site inbox and achievements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213600)

Comment: That question talks mainly about the mobile website UI, not the full desktop UI. Correct me if I'm wrong but there will be differences between the mobile webpage and the desktop webpage, will there not ?

Comment: I very much suspect that the Android App and the mobile web interface suffer from the same problem: that they are using the *old* architecture for handling notifications, as opposed to the new architecture created with the top-bar design change.

Comment: The other question mainly talks about how the notifications are not marked as read when looking at the mobile web interface. Your question mainly talks about how the notifications are not marked as read when looking at the android interface. See the similarity?

Comment: I am talking about android app to desktop UI correlation. My question is about notifications in the android app. That question is about the mobile web site. Also, I had no idea that they use the same architecture to handle the notifications. But still, does not make this question a dupe.

Comment: Yes it does; solving one solves the other.

Comment: AFAIK, as of v1.0.83, this has been fixed, either on mobile side, or API side.